# Error installing dplyr library in R v4.2.2

Tags: r, dplyr

I have updated my R version, and then updated my Rstudio, and now I am trying to install library(dplyr), but I get the following error:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
```

and when I try installing the library(vctrs) as @MrFlick suggested, and run library(dplyr) again, it shows that a dependency called 'xfun' is not installed. When I try...

```
** package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xfun’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/xfun’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Are you trying to install the package from source? If the binary version will do first use `install.packages("vctrs", type="binary")` then try to install dplyr again.

Comment: The moment I run the command library(dplyr) my r session aborts: R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated. It's very weird, it was all working well why did I update my rstudio damn it.

Comment: I would try `install.packages("xfun", type="binary")` next. Did you update your OS too? These "invalid active developer path" messages means you don't have the build tools installed on your mac. You can try `xcode-select --install` from the terminal to set that up. But if it ever asks you if you want to build from source, make sure you do not choose that option. Just use the prebuilt binaries.